# Exception Handling and Scope

Tags: c++, exception, scope

So I have to write this code for a hangman game, and I am supplied with a dicitonary.txt file which contain 127k words each on a separate line. What I did is I used a `map<int, set<string>> DICTIONARY;` to store words based on their letter count. So I have this code here but I have few issues:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
   map<int, set<string>> DICTIONARY;

   try{
      ifstream file("dictionary.txt");
      if(file.is_open()){
           string TEMP_INPUT;
           for(int i = 0; i < 127143; i++){
               file >> TEMP_INPUT;

               DICTIONARY[TEMP_INPUT.length()].insert(TEMP_INPUT);
           }
      }
      else throw 404;
   }catch(int x){
         cout << "Error: " << x << " - file not found!" << endl;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

But what I get is an error saying that DICTIONARY was not defined in that scope. I know that what is in the `if(){}` etc. stays in it, it's called scope. But how should I access that map?

I assume a pointer but still don't know how to use it in the scope.

And if someone could also show me how instead of using the 127.. in the `if` statement for less than `i` I can use a `while` not end of file or something similar?

The error output is:

```
source.cpp In function 'int main()':
source.cpp:14:24: error: 'DICTIONARY' was not declared in this scope
source.cpp:14:21: error: '>>' should be '> >' within a nested template argument list
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Could you make sure this is the actual code, and append the actual compiler output?

Comment: It is the actual code, I shall post the output just now.

Comment: The code is compiled successfuly.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow well that's weird :/

Comment: Even my g++ produces better error messages. Out of interest, what compiler do you use?

Comment: @JoSo so it happens that g++ on Linux :P

Comment: Mine doesn't produce this confusing second line, at least by default.

Comment: @JoSo this world is full of mysteries and weird things :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map<int, set<string>>` wasn't syntactically conforming C++ until C++11. The error `'DICTIONARY' was not declared in this scope` is misleading, the reason is that the compiler didn't accept `map<int, set<string>> DICTIONARY` as a variable declaration, and didn't add DICTIONARY to the identifier table.

Replace that with `map<int, set<string> >` (note the added whitespace)

... Or try to compile your code as C++11 if the compiler supports that. C++11 brings major improvements to C++!

Comment: Oh my god yes that worked! Thank You!!
I had read that somewhere but totally forgot about it! Thank you again!